# Which keystore is used when null is passed to KeyManagerFactory.init() in Java?

Tags: java, ssl

When I execute the following code:

```
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory             
                .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(null, null);
```

and then the subsequent establishment of the ssl connection, I get a `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` and not a NullPointerException or something. Which keystore is used then? Or is the NPE hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `null` is used as the keystore argument of `KeyManagerFactory.init(..., ...)`, no keystore is used (it's in fact using [an empty list](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java#L86) internally).

There's no "hidden" `NullPointerException` as such, and there's no reason why there should be one. Of course, using a `null` value here and an empty collection has consequences when trying to use a keymanager, but not all SSL/TLS connections require a keystore (e.g. client-side without client certificate or anonymous cipher suites).

(Note that, although there is no default value for the keystore, [there is one for the truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#InstallationAndCustomization), so that default value would be used with `TrustManagerFactory.init(null)`.)